# Unable to reach Tomcat via EC2 public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I've starting running a Tomcat 10 instance on my newly spun up EC2 instance but I'm unable to access it via the Public DNS. I've been doing a bit of googling and tried a combination of things, but nothing seems to allow me to access it.

My inbound rules are set up to allow inbound connections for HTTP and HTTPs on all Public IPv4 and IPv6 sources.

[image: inbound rules]

I can `curl localhost:8080` and get the contents of the Tomcat starter page.

Performing netstat gives the impression that things are listening:

```
$ netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44204         127.0.0.1:8080          TIME_WAIT
tcp        0    332 172.31.46.103:22        81.101.153.43:50078     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 172.31.46.103:68        0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7
```

And I believe I've set up the connector tag in the server.xml correctly:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            address="0.0.0.0"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
        maxParameterCount="1000"
        useIPVHosts="true"
           />
```

Is there anything else I may be missing or is my configuration wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My inbound rules are set up to allow inbound connections for HTTP and HTTPs on all Public IPv4 and IPv6 sources.

Those rules open up port `80` (HTTP) and port `443` (HTTPS). Your Tomcat server is listening on port `8080`. Just like you had to append `:8080` to `localhost` to get the local `curl` command to work, you will have to append `:8080` to the public IP in order to access the server from the web browser.